Help to get driver for D-link wireless wifi adapter (AX300 DWA-x305)
I bought the D-link wireless wifi adapter (AX300 DWA-x305) to use with Ubuntu 24.04 but it does not plug and play use.  i cannot find the driver in Dlink website too and i notice in dlink manual it is use aic8800fc. please kindly help suggest how to find and install driver for this device. Thank you

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lsusb
